# create view in redshift particular schema

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, sql-view

I've created an external schema in my redshift database using the script below:

```
create external schema exampleschema
  from data catalog database 'examplesource'
  iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::627xxxxx:role/dxxxx'
  region 'us-west-2'
  CREATE EXTERNAL DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS;
```

I'm now trying to create a view in that exampleschema schema using the script below, but I seem to only be able to create views in the "public" schema.  How do I create a view in the exampleschema schema?

```
create view vw_ticket as select * from exampleschema.ticket
with no schema binding;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the schema in the CREATE statement i.e. `create view exampleschema.vw_ticket ...`